# American Gods: How is this crucial word translated in non-English translations?

Tags: translation, american-gods

In the English novel American Gods, Neil Gaiman uses a neat linguistic 'trick', or wordplay, that affects several significant story points:

> The fact that the word `trunk` has four+ meanings in US English is artfully utilized: In chapter 15, Shadow notes that the mouse is in the elephant-headed man's `trunk`, which the elephant-headed man tells him to not forget. Later, in chapter 19, Mr. Nancy takes aspirin from an old wooden chest -- a `trunk`, which jogs Shadows memory about the elephant-headed man's words; initially thinking he meant the `trunk` of the tree. Eventually this leads him to the car on the ice at Lakeside in chapter 20, where he looks inside the `trunk` of the car to find something significant.

> Other languages may not have this quadruple meaning, at the very least in my native Dutch the word for an elephant's trunk (slurf) is nothing like the word for a tree's trunk (stam) or a car's trunk (koffer / kofferbak), although 'koffer' can indeed also be used for a chest.

I'm curious how translations in other languages handle this; specifically, if the mentioned passages are still linked to each other in a similar way in the translated version. Examples are welcome.

*Note: I did not see the TV show yet*

Comment: Note that this doesn't technically even work in English, just American.

Comment: No details at https://journal.neilgaiman.com/2003/05/more-on-translations.asp although Gaiman mentions the Spanish and French translations.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-spanish/trunk

Comment: If any moderator is listening: I'm uncertain how to select an accepted answer for this question format, since there are multiple relevant answers each for a singular language. Any tips are welcome.

Comment: @dennis_vok I am not a moderator, but this seems very straightforward: acceptance is up to the discretion of the person asking the question, so you pick the answer you like best (although might want to wait another day or two to see if any more interesting answers come in).

Comment: Is American Gods specifically written in US English? (Gaiman himself is English.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @EikePierstorff

Comment: @N.Virgo good question, I'm not sure what brand of English he uses (full disclosure: I listened to the audio book, so I did not actually see the spelling)

Comment: I think this opens up the bigger question of the extent to which a translator should be made aware of subtleties of word choice by the publisher... and whether the publisher is even a "reliable source" for a recent work. Fausto Balestra points out that in Italian two of the word choices match, and while that could be a linguistic coincidence it might also mean that the translator thought that he'd satisfied the "remember that" admonition, and didn't look for one or possibly two more occurrences.

Comment: @N.Virgo I'm not sure which the book is written in, but Shadow is definitely American, so even if the book is in British English, him making the connection of trunk to the _boot_ of the car wouldn't be weird to a Brit (given how much exposure we have to US media, we generally understand most such lexical differences without trouble)

Comment: @Tristan oh sure, I was just curious about whether Gaiman used American spellings etc. in his book about America - I guess it would kinda make sense if he did.

Comment: Gaiman usually writes in British English. For American Gods he made the conscious effort to use American English, with some help from his editor. This is mentioned in the foreword.

Comment: Make your own answer as a CW and put links to the Spanish, German, and Italian answers.

Comment: @DavidW Your phrasing is unnecessarily inflammatory—American English is a major dialect of English, just like British English.

Comment: I haven't read the book but in Fench there are combinations that can fit: "coffre" is the same word for a wooden chest and a car's ones. "tronc" is the same word for a tree trunk and the torso (probably the same origin as the english word). And we have a saying "avoir du coffre" that is about the chest, specifically a loud voice. About Mark Morgan Lloyd's comment, we have many bad translations in french, specially in SF / Fantasy, sometimes it's so bad that you can litterally guess the original english expression. Happily the genre gained popularity, nowadays it's better than some decades ago

Answer (score 22):

I will deal with the Spanish version, namely the translation by [Mónica Faerna](https://www.rocalibros.com/roca-bolsillo/catalogo/Neil+Gaiman/American+Gods).

When Shadow ("Sombra") is tied to the tree, and in delirium sees the elephant-headed man playing with a mouse which disappears, Shadow comments:

> Está en el **tronco**

which indeed means "It is in the trunk", but the word *tronco* here refers to the trunk of a tree. This does not have the wordplay in the English text - the trunk of an elephant is *la trompa*, and trunk in the sense of a chest or wooden container would either be *un baúl* or *un cofre*. This does relate to Shadow's later realization:

> " 'It's in the trunk,' " he said. "I knew it was important, but I
> didn't know why. I thought maybe it meant the trunk of the tree. But
> he wasn't talking about that at all, was he?"

Since Shadow thought at the time that the elephant-headed man meant the trunk of the tree, this means that the translator is essentially forced to use the word *tronco* here.

Later when Mr Nancy takes aspirin from his wooden trunk, it is referred to as *un cofre*:

> Del debajo del **cofre** sacó un frasco de ácido acetilsalicílico de
> tamaño familiar...
>
> -Bonito **cofre** - le dijo Sombra.

*Un cofre* is indeed a wooden chest, of the sort pirates use to store their doubloons and treasure.

Finally the "trunk" of the car on the ice is simply referred to as *el maletero*, which is the standard word used for this part of a car.

So in the Spanish text, the three (or four, if you include the elephant's trunk) meanings of trunk are rendered with different words, and so all traces of the wordplay have been lost. Shadow's realization of the significance of the word trunk also becomes rather baffling, although the translator does include a footnote:

> El autor juega con las diferentes acepciones de la palabra *trunk*:
> tronco, baúl, maletero.

that is:

> The author is playing with the different meanings of the word
> *trunk*: (tree)trunk, chest, trunk of a car.

Even with this footnote the wordplay is pretty hard to understand, without knowledge of the original text. And this is why it is almost always better to read an author in the original, rather than in translation.

Comment: Great answer, thank you, this is indeed what I would expect to happen for at least a subset of translations

Comment: If any moderator is listening: I'm uncertain how to select an accepted answer for this question format, since there are multiple relevant answers each for a singular language. Any tips are welcome.

Comment: @dennis_vok with the decline in importance of accepted answers (many sites no longer even put them at the top by default) I wouldn't overthink it. If you really want to award a tick, I'd give it to the answer you subjectively find best-written/most interesting

Comment: for more translation confusions, don't be afraid to look up how the Simpsons "die bart, die" was translated into German. (Spoiler: Not well)

Comment: In this type of context, there should at least be a translator's note mentioning the multiple meanings in the original language

Comment: @TeleportingGoat She did put a footnote - I've added it into my answer now

Answer (score 13):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

Your question intrigued me enough to spend the money for a German translation of "American Gods" that I don't have real use for, especially since it seems to be quite bad - which is a bit of a surprise, because it was translated by [Hannes Riffel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannes_Riffel), who is usually rather good at his job.

As for how the crucial wordplay is translated, rather badly I'm afraid.

In the scene Ganesha comes riding in on a mouse which then shrinks and is nowhere to be seen. Shadow notices the mouses tail in Ganeshas trunk and says

> "Na, sie wird noch in deinem Rüssel versinken"

Meaning,

> "Well, it [sc. the mouse] will drown in your trunk"

("sinken" is actually "sink", but in context probably means "drown")

to which Ganesha replies

> "Ja, sie wird versinken. [...] Du wirst vieles vergessen. Aber nicht
> das".

meaning

> "Yes, she will drown [...] You will forget many  things. But not
> this".

So they moved the wordplay from the word "trunk" (wich would not work in German, the translations are "Rüssel", "Truhe" und "Kofferraum" respectively) to the verb "sinken". Only that does not work at all, because "in einem Rüssel versinken" is not a phrase that makes any sense in German (it is understandable in context, but not natural).

I cannot see that there would have been a good way to translate this to German, but this translation attempt seems more clumsy than necessary.

Comment: Great answer, thank you, and bonus points for taking the trouble to acquire the book! Nice to see how the German strategy is different from the Spanish in moving the wordplay to another word

Answer (score 8):

In Russian, the four meanings have distinct words for them: an elephant's trunk is хобот, a trunk of a tree is ствол, a chest is сундук and a car trunk is багажник.

I have access to two Russian translations. While a translation by Reshetnikova and Mikhailin does not acknowledge the wordplay, a translation by Komarinets adapts Ganesha's words in chapter 15 to foreshadow the later events.

Komarinets, chapter 15, emphasis mine:

> – В стволе, – сказал Тень слоноголовому, следившему за тем, как исчезает, вильнув, мышиный хвост.
>
> Слоноголовый бог кивнул огромной головой и сказал:
>
> – Да. **В сундуке, в багажнике, в стволе… Смотри, слова не перепутай.** Ты многое забудешь. Ты многое отдашь. Ты многое потеряешь. Но этого не потеряй…

Literal translation back to English:

> – In the [tree] trunk, – said the Shadow to the elephant-headed, who was watching the mouse tail wiggling and disappearing.
>
> The elephant-headed god nodded his huge head and said:
>
> – Yes. **In the chest, in the [car] trunk, in the [tree] trunk... Make sure not to confuse the words.** You'll forget a lot. You'll give away a lot. You'll lose a lot. Don't lose this...

Comment: Great info, yet another strategy, very cool to know, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I haven't the book at hand so I can't confirm, but in Italian while the word for the elephant's trunk is "proboscide", both the chest and the car's trunk can be translated with the same word "baule".

Comment: Great info, thank you. Now I'm extra curious if/how the Italian translation links the chest part to the elephant part.

Answer (score 5):

### Polish translation

Since there is no way to make the wordplay on words *trąba* (elephant's trunk), *pień* (a tree trunk) and *bagażnik* (a car trunk), the translator - Paulina Braiter - used a different trick: she used an antiquated word *kufer* (coffer):

This is a "Kufer":

[image: A wooden coffer]

This is also a "Kufer"

[image]

So by an extension, so is this:

[image]

Now, what this has to do with the scene with Ganesha? When the elephant-headed god performs his trick, Shadow says:

> Magiczny **kufer** - powiedział Cień. W głębi pnia widział przed chwilą znikający ruchomy ogon.
> Człowiek-słoń skinął olbrzymią głową.
> Tak. **W kufrze**. Zapomnisz o wielu rzeczach, wiele innych oddasz i stracisz, ale nie zapomnij o tym

Which translates as

> Magic coffer - said Shadow. The moment before he could see the tail disappearing into the tree trunk.
> The elephant-man noded his huge head
> Yes. In the coffer. You will forget many things, but not that.

The words "magic coffer" can mean many things, but in this case, this suggests a name of a magic trick, with the mouse disappearing via some sort of hidden mechanism (or the dexterity of the magician). It is a bit clumsy, but understandable.

Later on, when Shadow has a headache, Mr Nancy reaches to his wooden "kufer" to get some aspirin, which prompts Shadow to recall this memory.

Comment: Thanks, another different but clever strategy!